# Let G be a group of order at least three in which all non-identity elements have order 2. Prove that G has a subgroup of order 4.

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group of order at least three in which all non-identity elements have
order 2. Prove that G has a subgroup of order 4.

I'm not sure why the group's order is at least three and not four. It would have to be four to have a subgroup of four. Also it cannot be three if all non-identity elements have order 2. Since there is always an odd number of elements with order 2.

Comment: Hint : the group is abelian.  The at least $3$ rules out $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: The statement could be of order at least $4$, but at least $3$ suffices.  You can rule out the group of order $3$ because the order of an element must divide the order of the group.  I suspect you are expected to rule it out in your proof.  Note that you are not told there is a subgroup of order $4$, you are to prove that.

Answer (score 1):

$abab=1$ implies $a(abab)=a=bab$ implies $ab=babb=ba$. There exists $b$ distinct of $1$ and $a$,$ab$ is not $a$ if $ab=a$, $a^2b=a^2=1=b$ contradiction. We also have $ab\neq b$. So the subgroup $\{1,a,b,ab\}$  is a subgroup of  order 4. To see this you just have to show that it is stable by the group law: $aba=ba^2=b$ since $ab=ba$ and $bab=b^2a=a$.